# gcd of $X^a - 1$ and $X^b - 1$

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I can prove that $X^a - 1 \mid X^b - 1$ if $a\mid b$, and even that the integer division of $a$ by $b$ translates in some sense into a division of $X^a$ by $X^b$. However, I do not know how to deduce
$$\gcd(X^a-1, X^b-1) = X^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$$

I would like to know both formally why it can be proved, but also if there is something deeper to be understood (e.g. if there is a hidden notion of "morphism preserving the integer division" or so)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can show that for $m\ge n$ we have
$$
\gcd(X^m - 1, X^n - 1) = \gcd(X^{m-n}-1, X^n-1), \tag{$\star$}
$$
which mimics $\gcd(m,n)=\gcd(m-n,n)$ exactly and allows you to perform the Euclidean algorithm on $m$ and $n$ instead of $X^m-1$ and $X^n-1$.

Here's the proof of $(\star)$:
\begin{align}
\gcd(\color{red}{X^m - 1}, \color{blue}{X^n - 1}) 
&= \gcd(\color{red}{X^m-1}-X^{m-n}(\color{blue}{X^n-1}), \color{blue}{X^n-1}) \\
&= \gcd(\color{green}{X^{m-n}-1},\color{blue}{X^n-1}).
\end{align}

Thus, using the same steps as in the Euclidean algorithm for $\gcd(m,n)$ you end up with
$$
\gcd(X^m-1,X^n-1) = \gcd(X^{\gcd(m,n)}-1,\underbrace{X^0-1}_0) = X^{\gcd(m,n)}-1.
$$

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).